# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting this error and it is originating from jquery framework.
When i try to load a select list on document ready i get this error.
I can't seem to find why i'm getting this error.

It works for the change event, but i'm getting the error when trying to execute the function manually.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined -> jquery-2.1.1.js:7300

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CourseSelect").change(loadTeachers);
    loadTeachers();
});

function loadTeachers() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: '/Manage/getTeachers/' + $(this).val(), 
        dataType: 'json', 
        cache: false,
        success:function(data) { 
            $('#TeacherSelect').get(0).options.length = 0;    
            $.each(data, function(i, teacher) {
                var option = $('<option />');
                option.val(teacher.employeeId);
                option.text(teacher.name);
                $('#TeacherSelect').append(option);
            });
        },         
        error: function() { 
            alert("Error while getting results"); 
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When you call `loadTeachers()` on DOMReady the context of `this` will not be the `#CourseSelect` element.

You can fix this by triggering a `change()` event on the `#CourseSelect` element on load of the DOM:

```
$("#CourseSelect").change(loadTeachers).change(); // or .trigger('change');
```

Alternatively can use `$.proxy` to change the context the function runs under:

```
$("#CourseSelect").change(loadTeachers);
$.proxy(loadTeachers, $('#CourseSelect'))();
```

Or the vanilla JS equivalent of the above, `bind()`:

```
$("#CourseSelect").change(loadTeachers);
loadTeachers.bind($('#CourseSelect'));
```

Answer (score 30):

I had the same problem, I was trying to listen the change on some select and actually the problem was I was using the event instead of the event.target which is the select object.

**INCORRECT :**

```
$(document).on('change', $("select"), function(el) {
    console.log($(el).val());
});
```

**CORRECT :**

```
$(document).on('change', $("select"), function(el) {
    console.log($(el.target).val());
});
```

Comment: In my particular case, I had to change "$(this).val();" to "$(this.target).val();"

Comment: But we want to avoid using `this` if we can help it.  Using `this` makes the code more difficult to maintain.

Comment: `$(document).on('change', "select", function(el) {` would also work

Answer (score 5):

It causes the error when you access `$(this).val()` when it called by change event `this` points to the invoker i.e. `CourseSelect` so it is working and and will get the value of `CourseSelect`. but when you manually call it `this` points to document. so either you will have to pass the `CourseSelect` object or access directly like `$("#CourseSelect").val()` instead of `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 5):

This Works For me !!!

**Call a Function without Parameter**

```
$("#CourseSelect").change(function(e1) {
   loadTeachers();
});
```

**Call a Function with Parameter**

```
$("#CourseSelect").change(function(e1) {
    loadTeachers($(e1.target).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It fails "`when trying to execute the function manually`" because you have a different 'this'. This will refer not to the thing you have in mind when invoking the method manually, but something else, probably the window object, or whatever context object you have when invoking manually.

Answer (score 1):

your $(this).val() has no scope in your ajax call, because its not in change event function scope

May be you implemented that ajax call in your change event itself first, in that case it works fine.
but when u created a function and calling that funciton in change event, scope for $(this).val() is not valid.

simply get the value using id selector instead of

```
$(#CourseSelect).val()
```

whole code should be like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#CourseSelect").change(loadTeachers);
    loadTeachers();
});

function loadTeachers()
{
    $.ajax({ type:'GET', url:'/Manage/getTeachers/' + $(#CourseSelect).val(), dataType:'json', cache:false,
        success:function(data)
        { 
            $('#TeacherSelect').get(0).options.length = 0;    

            $.each(data, function(i, teacher) 
            {
                var option = $('<option />');
                option.val(teacher.employeeId);
                option.text(teacher.name);
                $('#TeacherSelect').append(option);
            });
        }, error:function(){ alert("Error while getting results"); }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy solution to solve this problem :

first try to find `toLowerCase` Globally in your project. If it is found then try to add ? before toLowerCase.

```
Example: str?.toLowerCase()
```

if toLowerCase is not found in the project then simply

```
clear your browser history and cache.
```

I hope it will work.