# Why is the value for "$(this.target).val()" (referencing an input element) "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This appears to be a "Catch-22" Situation.

There are several input elements to which I have assigned the "payments" class like so:

```
<input class="payments" type="number" step="0.01" min="0" id="airfare" />
```

I am responding to the change event for those elements:

```
Template.templatizer.events({
      'change .payments' : function(event){
         var paymentTot = $('#paymenttotal').val();
         paymentTot = paymentTot + $(this).val();
         $('#paymenttotal').val(paymentTot);
      }
  });
```

...but with the code above, after entering a value into one of the elements of class "payments" and blurring/exiting, I get, "*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined.*", apparently because I need to append a ".target" to the element as noted in lenybernard's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723005/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined).

But after doing that, changing the code to this:

```
paymentTot = paymentTot + $(this.target).val();
```

...while that *does* solve the "*Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined*" problem, I get "Undefined" as the value of paymentTot after this line runs (is "" prior to that):

```
paymentTot = paymentTot + $(this.target).val();
```

How can I avoid the "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined" AND get a value from the element which has invoked the event?

Comment: Where is `toLowerCase` in the above code?

Comment: You want to pass the event object to your handler -- which you are -- then use `event.target`, not `this.target`.

Comment: @tymeJV: I don't have a "toLowerCase"; it occurs apparently when not using ".target" with select elements. See the link in the post for the gory details about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `this`, use `event`, since `this` will be pointing to the function, and the `target` is actually in the `event` object passed by parameter to that function:

```
paymentTot = paymentTot + $(event.target).val();
```