# Getting strange error while fetching dynamic added textbox value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I am appending textbox as below:-

```
$.each(myDataJSON, function (index, value)
    {
           var newRow = "<tr><td><input type='text' class='txtBox' value="+value.Price+"/></td></tr>";          
        $('#myTable').append(newRow);
    })
```

Now after appending rows, desired html is rendered. Now I am associated the blur event to these textboxes as below:-

```
$(document).on('blur','.txtBox',function(e)
{
    var newTextValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(newTextValue);//this throws below error 
    //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
});
```

However,if I try to patch it. Then the above error goes off but it doesn't reflect the new updated value but the old value. Only for the first dynamically added textbox,it gives the new updated value but not for the other textboxes.

```
    $(document).on('blur','.txtBox',function(e)
{
    var newTextValue = $('.txtBox').val();
    console.log(newTextValue);//no error 
});
```

Strange is that when I check html in inspection window none of the textbox value is updated.

My question here is

### How to get the updated value of textbox for dynamically added textboxes

Plus,
**Is there any event other than focusout/blur so that I can get the updated textbox value, the moment user leaves the textbox irrespective of waiting for the click event outside the textbox**

Comment: `console.lo(` it should be `console.log(` typo mistake. Have you used anywhere `toLowerCase()`??

Comment: Its typo mistake while typing the question here

Comment: try `this.val()` instead of `$(this).val()`

Comment: checked Uncaught TypeError: this.val is not a function

Comment: i think you should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723005/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined

Comment: Do `$(e.target).val()`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi.. ya it worked, but can you look into event thing that I have asked in the question.Please check Plus:- Is there any....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101468/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-chetan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails "*when trying to execute the function manually*" because you have a different `this`. event this points to the **invoker**

You have to do

```
$(document).on('blur','.txtBox',function(e)
{
    var newTextValue = $(e.target).val();

});
```

Comment: It worked..but can you please explain me in short why $(this).val() is throwing error

Comment: your textbox generated dynamically and when event executed it points to invoker.

Comment: Parath, can you please tell me about event stuff that I have asked in the question..

Comment: You can use keyup event.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I think you are wrong. It doesn't matter that the html was generated dynamically, take a look at this example: http://jsbin.com/gohizuzaje/edit?html,js,console,output

Even if that was the case, it shouldn't throw error about toLowerCase, it shouldn't have anything to do with that method. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: keup is something different, I want that the moment user leaves the textbox, event should be fired because in case of blur it wait for a click event outside

Comment: you can try `focusout`

Comment: @Chetan can you write more code so i can explain more why it doesn't working.

Comment: @tuks i mentioned here invoker get changed. `this` points to another element. I asked for full code with `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me (logs the right values):

```
<html>
<body>
    <table id = "myTable">
    </table>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var newRow = "<tr><td><input type='text' class='txtBox' value='1.1'/>     </td></tr>";          
    $('#myTable').append(newRow);

    var newRow1 = "<tr><td><input type='text' class='txtBox' value='1.2'/></td></tr>";          
    $('#myTable').append(newRow1);

    $(document).on('blur','.txtBox',function(e)
{
    var newTextValue = $(this).val();
    console.log(newTextValue);//this throws below error 
    //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
});
</script>
</html>
```

Maybe you should check if something else is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('blur', '.txtBox', function (e) {
            var newTextValue = $(this).val();
            alert(newTextValue)
        });

        $('#addRow').click(function () {
            var szTr = "<tr><td><input type='text' class='txtBox' value='10'/>     </td></tr>";
            $('#myTable').append(szTr);

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="addRow" value="Add Row">Add Row</button>

    <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Headline</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Chetan plz check this :)