# using setInterval in ajax function returns 'toLowerCase' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I'm trying to call this function every x seconds but it returns this error:

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

..What?

This is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function update() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'config/db.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      search: $(this).val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $("#test1").html(result);
      console.log('calling test1');
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: 'config/db2.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      search: $(this).val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $("#test2").html(result);
      console.log('calling test2');
    }
  });
  setInterval(update, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any help? I looked up this error but I couldn't really find anything which I understood.

Comment: The code you posted has no `toLowerCase`

Comment: What are you trying to reference with `this` when calling val()?

Comment: @Phix True, but that _is_ the error that is logged in your console when you execute the snippet.

Comment: RIght, but without a reproducible example who knows.

Comment: What more of a reproducible example are you looking for @Phix? Executing the code in the question reproduces that error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23723005/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is  $(this). Jquery has a misleading error message when it can't find an attribute and since you are referencing $(this), which I think refers to your document object, it will be invalid considering document objects don't have a value attribute.

Give your search input an id like 'search_box' and then

```
$(document).ready(function update() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'config/db.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      search: $("#search_term").val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $("#test1").html(result);
      console.log('calling test1');
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: 'config/db2.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      search: $("#search_term").val()
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $("#test2").html(result);
      console.log('calling test2');
    }
  });
  setInterval(update, 1000);
});
```